# template0 and template1 database dropped accidently

Tags: postgresql

I did not know that `template0` and `template1` database templates are required in order to create empty databases. I deleted them in order to clear up postgres. Now I'm not able to create any new database. Gives me this error :

```
ERROR:  template database "template1" does not exist
```

What can I do to get things going once again. I'll be very thankful for any help.

Comment: I expect you can still create a new database by specifying one of your still existing databases as the template to use `CREATE DATABASE foo TEMPLATE bar;`. However if there is not to much data in the cluster I would probably prefer to backup the data and initialize a new data directory with initdb and restore the backup.

Comment: Yes, that is what saved my day. Found I could specify template myself on postgresql documentation :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Luckily I had `postgres` database preserved because it was required for the `postgres` user to log into `psql`. Thus, created a `template0` and `template1` database :

```
create database template0 TEMPLATE postgres;
```

and same for template1. Then executed :

```
update pg_database set datistemplate=true  where datname='template0';
```

for both databases to stop myself from accidentally deleting these templates again.

Everything works fine now :)

Answer (score 2):

On my CentOS 7 box, I was not so lucky as to still have a database to connect to.  However:

```
su postgres -c "initdb /var/lib/pgsql/data"
```

(as root) created a template0 and template 1 to work with.

Answer (score 2):

For postgres `12.3` the following worked for me.

I deleted `template1` not knowing what it was. I was able to create it from `template0`. You could also create it from `postgres`.

```
createdb -T template0 template1
```

```
createdb -T postgres template1
```

This is suggested in the docs -

> template1 and template0 do not have any special status beyond the fact that the name template1 is the default source database name for CREATE DATABASE. For example, one could drop template1 and recreate it from template0 without any ill effects.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html

Answer (score 0):

on my debian machine, i upgraded some clusters to version 11.
the template[01] databases on the target cluster have been dropped, rendering me with the ones from the older versions.

as root, i created a new cluster with pg_createcluster.

as user postgres:

dump the databases of the new cluster with pg_dumpall (with the --clean flag).

drop the new cluster.

import the resulted source in your cluster with psql.

i would remove the drop role postgres and creation of the same.

best regards,
alex

Answer (score 0):

in my case i just created database "template1" with postgres template because previously i dropped template1 database